# Infinite Scroll in Only HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Is it possible to implement infinite scroll with only HTML/CSS without JavaScript?

I know you can implement this in Javascript, but I'm curious if it's possible without just to keep the stack simpler.

Comment: for infinite scroll we need infinity html, seems like not possible   with only HTML and CSS

Comment: No, there would be no way to add any new content to make it infintely scroll after the initally set html content.

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly not possible with only HTML and CSS. HTML is a markup language and CSS is used for styling elements. You need JavaScript to detect when the user has scrolled to the bottom to fetch more content to add. Without it, you will need infinite content for the user to have an infinite scrolling experience.

Answer (score 2):

Well no. The reason being infinite Scroll is a functionality derived from some kind of programing logic that will execute when an event listener (onscroll for example) is triggered. You cant do that only with html, a tag based markup language, or css, a style sheet design language.